# Retaining Set Parameters

Tags: java, html, jsp

Say I have something similar to this bit of code below that "activates" upon submit:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
```

From what I understand, this sets the "foo" parameter to the value "bar", so when I call:

```
request.getParameter("foo") != null && request.getParameter("foo").equals("bar");
```

The boolean will not output true. However, if I were to paste in the URL again the boolean would output false because it is once again not set. How can I make it so that the hidden parameter is "saved" and set upon renavigation to the page?

Answer (score 0):

save the parameter value in the session and send it to the page when it reloads. If the session already have the value, set it otherwise put it as null

Answer (score 0):

you need  to do`request.getParameter("foo")` to get value of foo. If you want to pass another parameter  with name  `formIsFilled`  add another hidden paramter `<input type="hidden" name="formIsFilled" value="true">`

Comment: I edited my question; they were all supposed to be the same variable, ha ha.